# Font Awesome icon is not showing instead its showing square box in android studio

Tags: android, font-awesome

I'm using text view and set a font awesome image, but it's showing the only square box in android studio

Comment: Could you provide your code please ;-) ?

Comment: TextView finger_img;
finger_img = (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.fin_img);
        finger_img.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypeface(getActivity(), FontManager.FONTAWESOME_REGULAR));
        finger_img.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.biometric_icon));
        finger_img.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));                 
   <string name="biometric_icon" translatable="false">&#xf577;</string>

Comment: Could You do this properly ? please .. ;-)